# How can I add a new field in a Cassandra table with default value "whatever"?

Tags: cassandra, cql

How can I add a new field/column in a Cassandra table with default value "whatever" ? I know how to add a new column, however, need it to be set to a certain value.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is no cell default value in cassandra. Best option is to in your application identify null values and change it to the default.

Comment: But then cassandra doesn't have a way to query for null values, you might have to just run across all rows before it gets updated and set default values.
If you have, say million rows and you want to update 1000 at a time, then running the query will refetch already updated rows.

Comment: @bschandramohan it's not like you add columns every day. it's a non-issue for me.