# Is there a way to convert NULL to some value in Spring converter?

Tags: spring, cassandra, datastax-java-driver, spring-data-cassandra

The database (Cassandra) does not allow specifying a default value when adding new columns. New columns are therefore `null` for every row.

Now, we added a flag to our entity (which might get more entries in the future):

```java
enum UsageFlag {
    OTHER,
    SPECIAL_VALUE,
}
```

We also added a ReadingConverter:

```java
@ReadingConverter
public class UsageFlagReadingConverter implements Converter<String, UsageFlag> {
  @Nonnull
  @Override
  public UsageFlag convert(String source) {
    return source == null
        ? UsageFlag.OTHER
        : UsageFlag.valueOf(source);
  }
}
```

It should basically treat `null` as `UsageFlag.OTHER` while parsing any other non-null value as an enum member.

However, this does not work since according to the Spring docs, the [convert method of the Converter](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/convert/converter/Converter.html#convert-S-) is only called if the value is **not** `null`. Because of this, the field of that entity remains `null` if it is `null` in the database. It works fine *if* (and only if) there is a value. Since the entire column is null when creating it, this completely defeats the purpose of the `ReadingConverter`.

Cassandra does not seem to support setting a value for every row (like `UPDATE foo SET flag='OTHER' WHERE True`), so this seemed like a good option. We wanted to avoid touching every row in the database manually.

Is there any way we can use Spring to help in this situation? Or is there a way to solve this using CQL or Cassandra?

Edit: Some more context on the setup:

```java
public interface FancyEntityRepository extends MapIdCassandraRepository<FancyEntity> {
}

public class FancyEntity {
    @PrimaryKeyColumn(name = "id", ordinal = 0, type = PrimaryKeyType.PARTITIONED)
    private string id;
    private UsageFlag usage;
    // other columns omitted
    // getters and setter omitted for this example
}

// Somewhere in a service: 
FancyEntity fe = fancyEntityRepository.findOne("1");
System.out.println(fe.getUsage());
```

But I don't think that the behaviour of the converter is cassandra-specific.

The table was created and then altered this way:

```
CREATE TABLE FancyEntity (
    id TEXT,
    -- other columns omitted
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
ALTER TABLE FancyEntity ADD (
    usage TEXT
);
```

[Cassandra Docs on ALTER TABLE](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql-oss/3.3/cql/cql_reference/cqlAlterTable.html) and a related SO question [about altering tables with a default value](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48749253/785210).

Comment: Well presented. Can you add the code where you are doing the request ?

Comment: Can you provide [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: I added some more context on the Repository/Entity used - does this suffice?
@123 do you mean in a form of a GitHub repo or something? This could take some time to boil it down. I think the "real" solution is something that I'm missing about spring or cassandra.

Comment: @nikeee A github repo would probably be the most helpful, but sort of goes against the format of StackExchange unfortunately. I meant pretty much what you've edited in now, cheers.

Comment: Just to clarify, this statement is incorrect: **New columns are therefore null for every row**.  New columns simply do not have a value if one is not set.  CQL and Spring Data _abstract_ that concept away from you by _showing_ null, which is different from actually containing a value of null.  It's possible that Cassandra lightweight transactions could help you here: https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql-oss/3.3/cql/cql_using/useInsertLWT.html

Comment: Why don't you handle this case in your model? When using constructor creation, you can default to a specific value. Alternatively, you can initialize your fields and use property accessors instead of field access.

Comment: @mp911de For now, we use getters/setters that check for null and return/set the "real" default value. But this solution seems hacky.

Comment: @Aaron thanks for the correction. Does this work without specifying a `WHERE` clause or is there a way to do this for every row? We want to avoid doing a query for every entry.

Comment: Unfortunately, no.  If you want to write to every valid partition, you need to specify every partition.

Comment: Actually, that is the preferred approach. `Converter.convert(…)` accepts a non-nullable input type. During value retrieval from Cassandra, the column value is `null` and so the source type for the converter cannot be retrieved.

Answer (score 1):

Cassandra has sparse storage meaning that it does not store columns (fields in RDBMS) if they are not set. It is therefore incorrect to say that "new columns are `null`".

If you are using prepared statements, you need to call `BoundStatement.unset()` with native protocol v3 so that tombstones are not generated for `null` values.

Otherwise, it is fine to leave variables unset with native protocol v4 (Cassandra 2.2 or later). Cheers!